# What's the difference between typescript.js and typescriptServices.js?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript comes with 3 JavaScript compiled files in its 'bin' folder:

- tsc.js -- command-line-run compiler itself;
- typescript.js -- ??
- typescriptServices.js -- ??

I guess one of those should be 'TypeScript language service', but what's the other one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`typescript.js` is what's used by some random internal tools. There's not any real external-facing purpose for it, though for example you could use it to build something similar to the TypeScript Playground.

`tsc.js` is `typescript.js` plus the command-line front-end.

`typescriptServices.js` is `typescript.js` plus the language service (e.g. for providing Intellisense features)

Answer (score -1):

typescriptServices can also be used to transpile TS files on the fly, in node, or in the browser.

Comment: in the browser both have the same limitation. Both typescript.js and typescriptServices.js can be used straight forwardly to transpile and create individual SourceFiles and both will fail the same way while working with Program, TypeChecker, Transformation, LanguageService, etc. For that to work you need to provide a custom COmpilerHost, LanguageServiceHost, etc to support the browser. [This library](https://github.com/cancerberoSgx/typescript-in-the-browser) is about that.